# Differences between strings.Contains and strings.ContainsAny in Golang

Tags: go

In the source code:

```golang
// Contains returns true if substr is within s.
func Contains(s, substr string) bool {
    return Index(s, substr) >= 0
}

// ContainsAny returns true if any Unicode code points in chars are within s.
func ContainsAny(s, chars string) bool {
    return IndexAny(s, chars) >= 0
}
```

the only difference seems to be `substr` and `the Unicode code points in chars`. I wrote some test to test both of them. Their behaviors seem to be identical. I don't understand when to use which.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think two functions are totally different. Contains are used to detect if a string contains a substring. ContainsAny are used to detect if a string contains any chars in the provided string.

Comment: you can also check out http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#ContainsAny There are already a lot of examples there

Answer (score 0):

`Contains` function reports whether a sub-string is within the string. Whereas `ContainsAny` function reports whether any Unicode code points in chars are within the string. Look at the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Contains).

```
 func main() {
     fmt.Println(strings.Contains("seafood", "aes"))
     fmt.Println(strings.ContainsAny("seafood", "aes"))
     fmt.Println(strings.Contains("iiii", "ui"))
     fmt.Println(strings.ContainsAny("iiii", "ui"))
 }
```

The output is;

```
false
true
false
true
```